# get tfs iterations and display in the form of tree using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Here is my sample xml data which I want to populate in the form of a tree structure.

```
<Node NodeID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/ccd2111b-6ac1-4dfc-a3fd-0f0145f18822"     Name="Area" Path="\TestProjectByTFSAdmin_Ishwar\Area" ProjectID="vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/86413a3a-6cc7-41bb-bef3-68177d5a0c14" StructureType="ProjectModelHierarchy">
    <Children>
        <Node NodeID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/711bb211-c51b-4555-ae71-0993239d4248"   Name="Inbox" ParentID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/ccd2111b-6ac1-4dfc-a3fd-0f0145f18822" Path="\TestProjectByTFSAdmin_Ishwar\Area\Inbox" ProjectID="vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/86413a3a-6cc7-41bb-bef3-68177d5a0c14" StructureType="ProjectModelHierarchy" /> 
        <Node NodeID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/2a6fa306-2da2-457f-9dbd-fc02219d411f" Name="Recycle Bin" ParentID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/ccd2111b-6ac1-4dfc-a3fd-0f0145f18822" Path="\TestProjectByTFSAdmin_Ishwar\Area\Recycle Bin" ProjectID="vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/86413a3a-6cc7-41bb-bef3-68177d5a0c14" StructureType="ProjectModelHierarchy" /> 
        <Node NodeID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/469b5304-fdc8-4d5d-aecd-32a75558dfbb" Name="TestArea" ParentID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/ccd2111b-6ac1-4dfc-a3fd-0f0145f18822" Path="\TestProjectByTFSAdmin_Ishwar\Area\TestArea" ProjectID="vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/86413a3a-6cc7-41bb-bef3-68177d5a0c14" StructureType="ProjectModelHierarchy" /> 
    </Children>
</Node>
```

This data in the form of string I'm passing to the following jQuery method.

```
success: function (result) {
    var tree = $.parseXML(result.d);
    traverse($('#treeView li'),tree.firstChild)
    // this – is an &mdash;
    $('<b>–<\/b>').prependTo('#treeView li:has(li)').click(function(){
        var sign=$(this).text()
        if (sign=="–")
            $(this).text('+').next().children().hide()
        else
            $(this).text('–').next().children().show()
    })

    function traverse(node, tree) {
        var children = $(tree).children()
        node.append(tree.Name)
        if (children.length) {
            var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
            children.each(function () {
                var li = $('<li>').appendTo(ul)
                traverse(li, this)
            })
        } else {
            $('<ul><li>' + $(tree).text() + '<\/li><\/ul>').appendTo(node)
        }
    }
})
```

but I'm not getting the correct values in the tree structure.

Comment: What does this do? What values are you seeing?

Comment: I am getting value as node but i want to display name attribute for each node.

Comment: Did my edit to your code make it match what you are currently using? You were missing a close to your `success`, and I just added it to the end. I doubt your `traverse` function should be inside the success.

Comment: No i missed to paste the closing brace. With this code m getting the correct tree structure but values are not getting assigned to the nodes. I want to assign name attribute values to each node. Like i have "Inbox" "Recycle Bin" "Test Area" names.

Comment: If you could fix it so that it is right, that'd help not just answers for you, but other people who might have a similar problem.

Comment: ok,plz tell me how to change this code to get correct values for each node